# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous error? python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from math import *

def TentMap(a,x):
    if x>= 0 and x<0.5:
        return 2.*a*x
    elif x>=0.5 and x<=1.:
        return 2.*a*(1.-x)

# We set a = 0.98, a typical chaotic value
a = 0.98
N = 1.0

xaxis = arange(0.0,N,0.01)

Func = TentMap

subplot(211)

title(str(Func.func_name) + ' at a=%g and its second iterate' %a)
ylabel('X(n+1)') # set y-axis label
plot(xaxis,Func(a,xaxis), 'g', antialiased=True)

subplot(212)

ylabel('X(n+1)') # set y-axis label
xlabel('X(n)')   # set x-axis label
plot(xaxis,Func(a,Func(a,xaxis)), 'bo', antialiased=True)
```

My `TentMap` function isn't working properly. I keep getting the error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` I don't understand how I'm supposed to use those. Basically, the `TentMap` function takes a value X and returns a certain value depending on what X is. So if 0<=x<0.5 then it returns 2*a*x and if 0.5<=x<=1 then it returns 2*a*(1-x).

Comment: Why are you using it directly, given that part of the name is ["map"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)?

Answer (score 3):

If you compare a numpy array with a number, you'll get another array:

```
>>> from numpy import arange
>>> xaxis = arange(0.0, 0.04, 0.01)
>>> xaxis
array([ 0.  ,  0.01,  0.02,  0.03])
>>> xaxis <= .02
array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The problem starts when you want to `and` this with something else, or use it in a boolean context:

```
>>> xaxis <= .02 and True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> bool(xaxis <= .02)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And that's what you're trying to do in the constructor of your `TentMap`. Are you sure you don't need to use `a` where you're using `x`?

Comment: Yeah I'm supposed to use x

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.vectorize` to get around this error which occurs when using `and` with a scalar value and arrray. The call looks like

```
np.vectorize(TentMap)(a,xaxis)
```